# ng-repeat data flashes then disappers

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have the following .json file:

```
[
{
    "host": "host00",
    "avgcpu": "1%",
    "maxcpu": "2%",
    "freem": "32000"
},
{
    "host": "node01",
    "avgcpu": "33%",
    "maxcpu": "80%",
    "freem": "64000"
},
{
    "host": "node02",
    "avgcpu": "55%",
    "maxcpu": "75%",
    "freem": "100000"
},
{
    "host": "node03",
    "avgcpu": "85%",
    "maxcpu": "100%",
    "freem": "86674"
},
{
    "host": "node04",
    "avgcpu": "3%",
    "maxcpu": "7%",
    "freem": "86613"
}
]
```

I try to read it with the following controller:

```
angular.module('usagemdl').controller('usagectrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/out/usage.json')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.usages = response.usages;
    });
}]);
```

And then i try to display it with the following html code:

```
<div class="cards" ng-controller="usagectrl">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" ng-repeat="usage in usages">
            <div class="card-header">
                {{ usage.host }}
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ usage.avgcpu }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ usage.maxcpu }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ usage.freem }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`ng-app` is defined in my `<body>` which works properly in a different scenario.

Im not sure what im doing wrong.
I can see a empty card for a second but then it dissappers.

Please let me know if you need any further code to find the issue.

Comment: What can you see in JS console?

Comment: My nodejs console gives no output.

Comment: Not nodejs console, but browser console

Comment: Google chrome - F12 ( windows )

Comment: Nothing, only output is that bootstrap.min.css.map is missing

Comment: you are using `.then()`, not `.success()`, _and there is nothing wrong about that, but_ the response is wrapped in an object with status, data, etc. So to get the data from JSON you need `response.data`, which in total makes: `$scope.usages = response.data.usages;`

Comment: Thank you, the solution is: `$scope.usages = response.data;`

Answer (score 0):

I this you should do that one. you are missing data from response.

```
angular.module('usagemdl').controller('usagectrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/out/usage.json')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.usages = response.data;
        console.log($scope.usages);
    });
}]);
```